# Mystifying failure of NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

Fitting the following two time-series (two repeats of the same exponential growth process)

```
ts1 = {{682, 98}, {739, 165}, {784, 286}, {826, 470}, {850, 618}, {871, 779}}
ts2 = {{683, 92}, {739, 174}, {785, 299}, {827, 489}, {851, 637}, {871, 807}}
```

with

```
NonlinearModelFit[ts, a Exp[b t], {a, b}, t, Method -> "NMinimize"]
```

produces two very different results:

[image]

I am at a loss to explain what's gone wrong. `"NMinimize"` has always worked very well, but I wonder if there are other precautions I should always take with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Providing a ballpark initial guess works for me: `NonlinearModelFit[ts, a Exp[b t], {a, {b, 1/800}}, t]`. Doesn't work with `Method -> "NMinimize"` though, which ignores it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NMinimize[]` with the Automatic method works nice ... sometimes.

You can help it by providing a better choice. Like in:

```
ts1 = {{682, 98}, {739, 165}, {784, 286}, {826, 470}, {850, 618}, {871, 779}};
ts2 = {{683, 92}, {739, 174}, {785, 299}, {827, 489}, {851, 637}, {871, 807}};
tt = {ts1, ts2};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[#, a Exp[b t];, {a, b}, t, 
     Method -> {"NMinimize", {Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}}] & /@ tt;

nlm[[#]]["BestFitParameters"] & /@ {1, 2}
(* {{a -> 0.0368246, b -> 0.0114384}, {a -> 0.0348901, b -> 0.0115362}} *)
```

---

The default was probably using "DifferentialEvolution", as you can see here:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[#,  a Exp[b t], {a, b}, t, Method -> {"NMinimize"}] & /@  tt;
nlm[[#]]["BestFitParameters"] & /@ {1, 2}
NMinimize[Total[(a Exp[b #[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ #], {a, b}, 
                 Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}] & /@ tt

(* {{a -> 9.60194, b -> 0.00477938}, {a -> 0.03489, b -> 0.0115362}}
   {{95044.8, {a -> 9.60194, b -> 0.00477938}},
    {27.3624, {a -> 0.0348901, b -> 0.0115362}}}
*)
```

But the problem is that the function is very flat in the region of interest:

```
GraphicsRow[
 ContourPlot[Total[(a Exp[b #[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ #], {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, .01}, 
            AspectRatio -> 1] & /@ tt]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, this is what is happening with the convergence:

```
ptsk = Reap[NMinimize[Total[(a Exp[b #[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ #], {a, b}, 
                      Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution"}, 
                      StepMonitor :> Sow[{a, b}]]][[2, 1]] & /@ tt;

GraphicsRow[ContourPlot[
    Total[(a Exp[b #[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ #[[1]]], {a, 0, 14}, {b, 0, .02}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
     Epilog -> {Red, Arrow /@ Partition[#[[2]], 2, 1]}] & /@ Transpose[{tt, ptsk}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Possibly a very small bump in a very flat surface is causing a large difference.

A more detailed view, where you can see the "return point" for the convergence:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yoohoo. Anyone listening to my comment [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66191/fitting-to-a-power-law-is-there-any-reason-to-fit-a-line-to-the-log-of-the-da)? If you linearize it makes for an easier problem to solve. In this example one gets a good result from `nlml = LinearModelFit[Map[{#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} &, #], {1, t}, t] & /@
    tt;

funx = Map[Exp[#[[1]]]*Exp[t*#[[2]]] &, 
  nlml[[#]]["BestFitParameters"] & /@ {1, 2}]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yup, but that takes out all the fun :)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau To be clearer: the question asked "why this happens".I tried to answer that.

Comment: Ignore the false indignation, I voted up your answer before I posted the silly comment. You did in fact explain the lame result. I just thought it funny that an example would come along so soon to justify the claim I had made in the prior comment.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau All's well. Your comment is _the_ way to go with the exponential model. As an aside, many years ago, while trying to model a relaxation process I found that sums of exponentials can be a pain in the.